# SSRS 208 R2 cross domain works with ip fails with name

Tags: windows, authentication, dns, ssrs-2008-r2

Background:
I have two trusted domains WMS and WMS1. SSRS 2008 R2 is running on WMS1 and the users are authenticated to WMS. WMS is a wind 2k3 r2 server ad WMS1 has a win 2k8 r2 server. The desktops are Win 7 64 bit. They are all on the same subnet 192.0.0.0. 192.0.0.9 is the SSRS server and its name is ssrs.WMS1.local

Issue:
When I open Internet Explorer and type //192.0.0.9/Reports from a desktop, the reports function as they should.
When I use //ssrs/Reports from the same desktop, The page opens up, but has the following error:
User WMS\user1 does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I am logged in as that same user and the permissions exist both in sql server and SSRS.

As an added piece of information, I can log into the SSRS sql server from the desktop using management studio using WMS\user1 credentials.

The importance is that a third party tool is also giving the same error and cannot use the ip.

Further investigation reveals that when using the ip, it asked for credentials where WMS1 login credentials were used.
Still no Idea how to remedy the issue.